# How do I get cfquery results in my .cfc file?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

My hope is to validate an input field (PromoCode) prior to form submission. @Adrian J. Moreno pointed me to "The Remember The Milk sign-up form" (https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/milk/) and @SOS has walked me through the process to this point.

I’ve got everything working (sort of) except grabbing the PromoCode from the DB (it’s currently hardcoded in the .cfc file.)

The site is for my brother who teaches multiple training courses and asked if I can add a promo code option to the registration form. He has several courses so there may be several promo codes (different for each possible course.)

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I grab the PromoCode for each course from SQL to compare to what the user types?
2. As indicated above, I’ve got everything else working except, currently, if the user types a wrong promo code it tells them it’s invalid as expected… BUT the user cannot submit the form unless they clear the field or enter the proper code. I’d like the user to be able to submit the form regardless of whether the PromoCode is valid or not. If it IS valid, they get the discount… if not, they don’t.

Here’s the stripped down code. I can provide the full code if necessary.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
            rules: {
                promocode: {
                    remote: "/components/promocodecomponent.cfc?method=validatepromocode"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                promocode: {
                    remote: jQuery.validator.format("<span class='text-danger font-weight-bold font-italic ml-2'>Sorry, {0} is not a valid Promo Code</span>")
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-10">
        <form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
            <input id="promocode" name="promocode" type="text" value="">
            <br>
            <input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CFC file:**

```
component {
    remote boolean function validatepromocode(string promocode) returnFormat="json"{
        
        if (arguments.promocode == "john") { //Need to replace "John" with #cfoutput#
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

**cfquery:**

```
<cfquery name="GetAllCourses" datasource="#request.dsn#">
        SELECT ID, EVENT_NAME, NPT_STORY_TYPE, STORY_TYPE, PICTURE, SHOWDATE, SHOWENDDATE, 
            SHOWTIME, SHOWENDTIME, REGISTRATIONTIME, DOORSOPEN, AGE, SEATS, FEE_ADVANCED, 
                FEE_DAYOFSHOW, PROMOCODE, VENUE, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SHOWDATE, 
                    PHONE, GOOGLEMAPADDRESS, COMMENTS, TEASER, REQUIREMENTS, 
                        STARTDATE, ENDDATE, SHORT_URL
                            FROM DBO.COURSES         
                            <cfif isDefined('url.sname')>
                                WHERE SHORT_URL = <cfqueryparam value="#TRIM(url.sname)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">  
                            <cfelseif isDefined('url.id')>
                                WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#url.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
                            </cfif>             
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Why aren't you trying to do a query inside of the cfc? I don't understand how they are supposed to work together.

Comment: @JamesAMohler - I think he's saying he's not sure how to work his existing query into the CFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each course can have its own promo code, then you'll need to pass both the "PromoCode" and "CourseId" values to the CFC. Use the [data](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) option to pass additional parameters to the [remote](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) url:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
        rules: {
            promocode: {
                remote: {
                    url: "/components/promoCodeComponent.cfc?method=validatePromoCode",
                    data: { 
                        courseId : $("#courseId").val() 
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            promocode: {
                remote: jQuery.validator.format("Sorry, {0} is not a valid Promo Code")
            }
        },
        errorClass: "text-danger",
        validClass: "text-success"          
    });
});
```

**Form**

```
<form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
    <!--- demo only --->
    Course Id: <input id="courseId" name="courseId" type="text" value=""><br>
    Promo Code: <input id="promocode" name="promocode" type="text" value=""><br>
    <input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup">
</form>
```

Modify your CFC function to accept an additional parameter: courseID. Inside the function, use [QueryExecute()](https://cfdocs.org/queryexecute) to lookup the promoCode and courseId in the database. If a match is found, return `true` (i.e. valid).

NB: Replace *"Your_DataSource_Name"* with your datasource name. See also the section titled ["Default Datasource"](https://modern-cfml.ortusbooks.com/cfml-language/queries).

```
component {
    // Note: See Application.cfc docs on setting application level datasource, i.e. "this.datasource"
    remote boolean function validatePromoCode(string courseId, string promoCode) returnFormat="json"{
        
        local.qPromoCode = queryExecute(
            "   SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalFound 
                FROM   Courses 
                WHERE  Id = :courseId 
                AND    PromoCode = :promoCode
                AND    LEN(PromoCode) > 0                                   
            "
            , { 
                promoCode = { value=arguments.promoCode, cfsqltype="varchar" }
                , courseId = { value=arguments.courseId, cfsqltype="integer", null=!isNumeric(arguments.courseId) }
              }
            , { datasource="Your_DataSource_Name" }
        );
                                        ;
        if (local.qPromoCode.TotalFound gt 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

---

**Update 2/20/2022**

Regarding question #2, I haven't tried anything like that with this plugin. What you describe sounds more like a "warning", and I don't think the plugin was designed for that. However, you might post a JS specific question to get a more definitive answer from those more familiar with the plugin.

If you're only using the plugin for this one field, using a bit of jQuery (instead of the plugin) might do in a pinch. Hook into the text field's [blur() event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event). When the field loses focus, call the cfc with [$.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). Then update a `<div>` with the response. The approach lacks the bells and whistles of the plugin (and could be improved, usability wise) but seems truer to your intent i.e. display warning vs hard fail.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // attach handler to all text fields with class ".promocode"
    $(".promocode").on( "blur", function(evt) {
    
        // promo code field that triggered event
        var txtPromo = $(this);
        // find nearest "course" id 
        var txtCourse = txtPromo.prevAll('.courseid').first();
        // find nearest "status" element 
        var elemStatus = txtPromo.nextAll('.promocode-status').first();
        
        // clear any previous status
        elemStatus.removeClass("text-success")
                .removeClass("text-danger")
                .html("");
                
        // nothing entered, nothing to do
        if (txtPromo.val().trim() == "") {
            return;
        }
        
        // verify promo code 
        $.getJSON( "/path/PromoCode.cfc"
            , { method : "validatePromoCode"
            , courseId: txtCourse.val()
            , promoCode : txtPromo.val()
        })
        .done(function( response ) {
            if (response.isValidCode) {
                elemStatus
                    .addClass("text-success")
                    .html("Success");
            }
            else {
                elemStatus
                    .addClass("text-danger")
                    .html("Sorry, "+ response.promoCode + " is not a valid Promo Code");
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```

**Form** (multiple promo code fields)

```
<!--- assign a "class" instead of "id" to identify each of the 3 elements in handler --->
<form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
   <div>
     Class 1: <input class="courseid" name="courseid" type="text" value="1">
     Promo Code: <input class="promocode" name="promocode" type="text" value="">
     <span class="promocode-status"></span>
   </div>
   <div>
     Class 2: <input class="courseid" name="courseid" type="text" value="2">
     Promo Code: <input class="promocode" name="promocode" type="text" value="">
     <span class="promocode-status"></span>
   </div>

   <input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup">
</form>
```

**CFC**

```
component {
    remote struct function validatePromoCode(string courseId, string promoCode) returnFormat="json"{
        
        local.qPromoCode = queryExecute(
            "   SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalFound 
                FROM   Courses 
                WHERE  Id = :courseId 
                AND    PromoCode = :promoCode
                AND    LEN(PromoCode) > 0                                   
            "
            , { 
                promoCode = { value=arguments.promoCode, cfsqltype="varchar" }
                , courseId = { value=arguments.courseId, cfsqltype="integer", null=!isNumeric(arguments.courseId) }
              }
            , { datasource="SQLServer" }
        );
        
        return { 
            "promoCode": arguments.promoCode 
            , "isValidCode" : (qPromoCode.TotalFound gt 0) 
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience and expertise. In regards to "Question 2" of this thread... is there a way to allow the user to submit the form without having to clear the PromoCode field if they've typed in the wrong code? I look at it this way... If they type in the wrong code, we told them it's wrong so they're on their own. Currently if there's an incorrect value in the field, the form will not submit unless the proper value has been entered or the field has been cleared. I'd hate to have the user not understand this and leave the site frustrated without registering.

Comment: I've never tried anything like that with this plugin. I'm only familiar with disabling validation entirely.  Tbh, I don't think the plugin is designed for this, but I'm not 100% sure. Maybe post a JS specific question and see if anyone has a more definitive answer on this.

Comment: Though if the plugin is only being used for this one field, a bit of jQuery might work instead.  Hook into the promoCode field's `blur` event and call the CFC using [$.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).  Then update a status `<div>` with the result. It's more manual than using the plugin, but is probably truer to your intent (i.e. Warn vs hard fail).

Comment: I've been searching all day to try to understand. So far the only thing I've seen that's close is here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/query-database-quot-onblur-quot-of-textbox/m-p/3140138 but it's using `bind` instead of `blur`.  Am I heading down the right path?

Comment: No, `bind` is a deprecated/discouraged CF option. [`blur` is an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event). See updated answer

Comment: I'm completely lost on this. I've posted another question more specific to JS as you suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198252/how-do-i-submit-a-form-if-ajax-validation-is-false

Comment: Read over the update above.  In short it says instead of using the plugin, try this jQuery code.  Play around with it to get a sense of how it works. ]

Comment: Also, I'd recommend omitting CF code when asking a JS question - or at least de-emphasizing it.  Primarily because javascript folks often ignore questions that are mix of JS and other languages X, Y or Z, thinking they don't know the answer because they don't know language X. Since your real question is about what you can or can't do with the validate plugin, consider posting only JS code in the form of a "fiddle", i.e. Using https://jsfiddle.net . Here is a starter fiddle. Note, it uses $.mockajax to simulate the CFC https://jsfiddle.net/zmf430u5/

Comment: I'm able to submit the form successfully with or without the proper promo code. However, the `#promocode-status` displays "Sorry, xxx is not a valid Promo Code" regardless of whether it is valid or not.

Comment: Curious as to what the `name="classId"` is doing and why its value is hardcoded.

Comment: Was trying to keep the example simple, but since you asked... Short answer - "class" can be used as a [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Long answer - the current code uses an `#id` to identify a single promoCode field. Id's must be unique in the DOM. If your form contains multiple promo fields, each field would need a unique id, requiring a handler for each one. To avoid that, you can use a `class` name as a selector, and add a handler to every field with that class name i.e. `$(".promocode").on( "blur", ....}` (note the use of `.className` instead of `#id`

Comment: (Edit) See updated answer above.  See also the jquery docs. They're a good resource and most pages have small, runnable, examples at the bottom demonstrating the concepts [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/), [prevAll](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/), etc...

Comment: You’re a Master! Although I didn’t need the most recent update (I used the first update from 2/20) once I realized you might be thinking there were multiple promo code fields in the form it all made sense. Although we have multiple courses, there’s only one promo code per course. The user selects a course taking them to `course/course-name` & clicks button to take them to `registration.cfm` where the form resides. We know what the course is at that point, including the courseID. So this made it all work.’<input id="courseid" type="hidden" value="<cfoutput>#GetAllCourses.courseid#</cfoutput>”>’

Comment: Gotcha. That'll work :-)

Comment: Thanks much for your patience and sticking with me. I owe you a cold brew! :)