# How do I submit a form if AJAX validation is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, jquery-validate

I’m trying to validate a PromoCode prior to form submission. I AM able to do that but if the result is false, I am unable to submit the form unless the input field has been cleared. I’m a self-taught hobby coder and don’t really understand JS, AJAX or cfcomponent (this is my first shot at all of it.) I’ve had a great deal of help getting to this point. All additional help is greatly appreciated.

**SUMMARY:**

- If the PromoCode the user types into the text field matches what’s stored in the DB… all is good. They submit the form and get the discount.
- If the PromoCode the user types into the text field does NOT match, they get the message “Sorry, that is not a valid promo code” but cannot submit the form unless the text field has been cleared.
- I need the user to be able to submit the form if the PromoCode is invalid… they just wouldn’t get the discount. We just told them it was invalid so they’re on their own. I'd hate to have the user not understand this and leave the site frustrated without registering.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#signupform").validate({
        rules: {
            promocode: {
                remote: {
                    url: "/components/promoCodeComponent.cfc?method=validatePromoCode",
                    data: { 
                        courseId : $("#courseId").val() 
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            promocode: {
                remote: jQuery.validator.format("Sorry, {0} is not a valid Promo Code")
            }
        },
        errorClass: "text-danger",
        validClass: "text-success"          
    });
});
```

**FORM**

```
<form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
    <!--- demo only --->
    Course Id: <input id="courseId" name="courseId" type="text" value=""><br>
    Promo Code: <input id="promocode" name="promocode" type="text" value=""><br>
    <input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup">
</form>
```

**CFC**

```
component {
    // Note: See Application.cfc docs on setting application level datasource, i.e. "this.datasource"
    remote boolean function validatePromoCode(string courseId, string promoCode) returnFormat="json"{
        
        local.qPromoCode = queryExecute(
            "   SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalFound 
                FROM   Courses 
                WHERE  Id = :courseId 
                AND    PromoCode = :promoCode
                AND    LEN(PromoCode) > 0                                   
            "
            , { 
                promoCode = { value=arguments.promoCode, cfsqltype="varchar" }
                , courseId = { value=arguments.courseId, cfsqltype="integer", null=!isNumeric(arguments.courseId) }
              }
            , { datasource=“My_DataSource_Name" }
        );
                                        ;
        if (local.qPromoCode.TotalFound gt 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: So, in other terms... the promocode isn't really required nor it has to be valid for submission?

Comment: That's correct. I simply want to alert the user to whether or not the promo code they enter is correct before they submit the form and register.

Comment: @AndreasRu - See their other thread for a possible option. Though I'd be interested in hearing other (better) options too. (Edit) I don't have time to review it now, but just came across this thread that sounds kinda like what they're trying to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581371/jquery-validation-plugin-how-can-i-treat-errors-as-warnings-and-allow-form-subm

Comment: IMO, I would simply clear out the field programmatically after it fails `remote` validation.  Since the field is not `required`, it would submit when empty.

Comment: A `window.confrm` control seems appropriate for this situation.  You can read about it here, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: Confirm's are disruptive and can be annoying to users. Especially when they occur multiple times. Use them sparingly.

Comment: @Sparky - Where would they put the code to clear the value, inside `invalidHandler()` maybe? Sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zmf430u5/ .

Comment: @SOS - the `invalidHandler` only fires when attempting to submit a form that fails validation.  It seems that clearing the field here would take two clicks of the submit button, which is not ideal.  I would write a completely independent handler that fires on the blur event of the remote field, checks to see if this field is invalid, and then clears it out.  Check the docs for the `.valid()` method.

Comment: @Sparky - Thanks. I'll have to play around with it some more.  It seems like `blur` fires before the `remote` call has completed. So the message isn't cleared until you re-focus the remote field a second time.  https://jsfiddle.net/2wmkgq90/

Comment: (.. and yes, I deliberately used a slight delay in the remote call ;-)

Comment: @SOS came up with a different solution that works as I had hoped. You can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166985/how-do-i-get-cfquery-results-in-my-cfc-file/71168585?noredirect=1#comment125880063_71168585 Thanks to all for your help.